# UIImagePickerController crashesdue to memory issues in ios 10

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I get random memory crashes with no memory warning. I have updated my ios to 10.0.2, my Xamarin to 6.2. I added camera usage description and photo library usage description, as suggested.

I have the following code in my FinishedPickingMedia callback

```
public async override void FinishedPickingMedia(UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
{
    try
    {
        // determine what was selected, video or image
        bool isImage = false;
        switch (info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString())
        {
            case "public.image":
                isImage = true;
                break;
            case "public.video":
                break;
        }

        if (isImage)
        {
            UIImage originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
            if (originalImage != null)
            {
                UIImageOrientation OrIn = originalImage.Orientation;
                Debug.WriteLine("scaling image");
                var originalImage1 = await Task.Run(() => ScaleAndRotateImage.ScaleAndRotateImageView(originalImage, OrIn));

                if (originalImage1 != null)
                {
                    var Data = originalImage1.AsJPEG(0.0f);

                    if (Data != null)
                    {
                        UIImage resizedImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(Data);
                        if (originalImage != null)
                        {
                            originalImage.Dispose();

                            originalImage = null;
                        }

                        originalImage1.Dispose();

                        originalImage1 = null;
                        Data.Dispose();
                        Data = null;
                        GC.Collect();

#if DEBUG
                        var Process1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                        if (Process1 != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("memory allocated by FinishedPickingMedia = {0}", Process1.WorkingSet64));
                        }
#endif
                        camController.ShowPhoto(resizedImage);
                    }

                    if (info != null)
                    {
                        info.Dispose();
                        info = null;
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception Occured in FinishedPickingMedia method due to " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // dismiss the picker
        picker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        picker.Dispose();
        picker = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

This seams to happen randomly, my application needs to capture more than 200 photos (archive) I researched on the internet and this seams to be an issue with iOS 10 and this control

Comment: dismiss picker at the beginning of this function. You can process image after that.   first line in this function should be.. picker.DismissModalViewController(true); . That will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!!